# Unreal: How to access image in MediaTexture with C++?

Tags: c++, textures, unreal-engine4, texture2d, unreal-blueprint

I'm currently using unreal read from video and cameras. I got a Media Player and Media Texture alongside with it.

I'm aware that It is possible to read pixels from Texture2D. The problem is mediaTexture is derived from Texture. Thus It cannot be casted to Texture2D. And I have no idea how to get pixel data from it.

Thanks for any reply! C++ and blueprint are both welcomed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At present, it seems like the only way is to render the media texture to a render target, and then read the result with ReadPixels. This is how Epic does it for their [OpenCV Calibration](https://github.com/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/blob/46544fa5e0aa9e6740c19b44b0628b72e7bbd5ce/Engine/Plugins/VirtualProduction/CameraCalibration/Source/CameraCalibrationEditor/Private/AssetEditor/CameraCalibrationStepsController.cpp#L1224)

Comment: I have looked into the link you provided. Yet I haven't seen any code that get data from `TWeakObjectPtr<UMediaTexture> MediaTexture;` to `TWeakObjectPtr<UTextureRenderTarget2D> MediaPlateRenderTarget;`. Probably I was missing something. Could you possibly explain a little bit about it?

Comment: I have some code that goes from MediaTexture->RenderTarget. I cannot share it, but the summary is that you load a basic plane and a material, then assign the MediaTexture to that material. Finally, you use UKismetRenderingLibrary::DrawMaterialToRenderTarget to render the material into your RenderTarget